# Select outside element of <header> and toggle only one element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm tryin to set up a new toggle function and well, it works but not as I want. It toggles the whole table and not only the selected part.

You can see a live demo here: http://cywa.eu/forum/index.php/Team/

My jquery looks like this:

```
$(function() {
        $('#switch .contentSwitch').hide();
        $('#switch header').click(function() {
            $('#switch .contentSwitch').toggle('slow');
            $('#switch header span:nth-child(2)').removeClass('icon-angle-down');
            $('#switch header span:nth-child(2)').addClass('icon-angle-up');
        });
    });
```

Please look for the html onto the website through the link above.
You will see 8 headers like Management and so on. And I want to toggle only one of it if i click on the element and not all. But I dont know, which selector I can use because the table is outside the header:

```
<header>
    <h2>.....</h2>
</header>
<table class="contentSwitch">....</table>
```

Moreover the toggle of the css class also won't work, I would be happy if you can fix this bad problem....

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` within your click handler to relate the elements you want to effect to the one which was clicked on. Try this:

```
$('#switch header').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.contentSwitch').toggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('icon-angle-down icon-angle-up');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, worked for me! I was unsure because of the fact that the table is outside the header...